# Django. How to return QuerySet order_by result of a fuzzy wuzzy method?

Tags: python, django, django-views, fuzzywuzzy

Here is my model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Item: {0}'.format(self.id)


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(, max_length=600, default='')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

I would like to query set Items, so it returns X items sorted by [Fuzzy wuzzy.](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)
Basically, I need to find matching Items and merge them.

I tried to create a dictionary, but it is extremely slow. I have about 80 000 items and it's still counting.

I tried to something like:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(status=3)
                 .annotate( score=fuzz.ratio(query,i.name_set.all().first().name))
                 .order_by('-score')
```

Can anyone give me some light on the topic?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are 80.000 entries in the database you have to consider the options:

(A) let the database sort (preferrably using some pre-created index) and return only the chosen rows. This allows for paging via the database.

(B) return everything from the DB as fast as possible and sort all 80.000 in RAM. If you want to stick to the python module FuzzyWuzzy you would have to do that. But as you have experienced by now, this might not be fast. You'd have to do paging on your own.

> [FuzzyWuzzy] uses Levenshtein Distance to calculate the differences between sequences in a simple-to-use package.

If you are using PostgreSQL as backend, you can use the levenshtein function as described here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

There seem to be contributions to Django to integrate this:
https://github.com/django/django/pull/4825

[TrigramSimilarity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramsimilarity) is already available. You could have a look at the source code and implement something similar based on the postgres levenshtein. But I'd recommend to first try it out. It might already suit your needs.

EDIT:

In general for tables of this size and more, make sure that your DB has indexes where required and makes use of them. For example: Django's `__icontains` filter is not covered by Django's `db_index`. You have to add a trigram index on that column yourself.

It could be that your current code takes this long because the query already takes unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **PostgreSQL** you can use [Trigram Similar](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#trigram-similarity)

`trigram_similar` lookup allows you to perform trigram lookups, measuring the number of trigrams (three consecutive characters) shared, using a dedicated **PostgreSQL** extension.

### Installation:

update your `settings.py`::

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]
```

add a new migration::

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

a new migration file will be created eg: `migrations/0002_auto_<date>_<time>.py`. update it::

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension
class Migration(migrations.Migration):        

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]
    operations = [
        TrigramExtension(),
    ]
```

now migrate:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

now you can use `trigram_similar` lookup on `CharField` and `TextField` eg:

```
>>> City.objects.filter(name__trigram_similar="Middlesborough")
['<City: Middlesbrough>']
```

Comment: This answer is seriously far better than the docs. Thank you!